# An error occurred while calling o196.showString

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting to know spark and wanted to convert a list (about 1000 entries) into a spark df.

Unfortunately I get the mentioned error in the title. I couldn't really figure out what causes this error and would be really grateful if someone could help me.
This is my code so far:

```
# Pyspark SQL library
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,isnan, when, count
from pyspark.sql.functions import countDistinct


import findspark

findspark.init("/usr/local/spark/")

spark = SparkSession.builder \
   .master("local[*]") \
   .appName("project") \
   .config("spark.executor.memory", "1gb") \
   .getOrCreate()
```

```
comments = ["string1", "string2", "string3",...]

schema = StructType([StructField('Comments', StringType(), True),])

# Convert list to RDD
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(comments)

# Create data frame
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schema)
print(df.schema)
df.show(5)
```

Here is the full error message:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-ff4bb233dd51> in <module>
      5 df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schema)
      6 print(df.schema)
----> 7 df.show(5)

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    438         """
    439         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 440             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    441         else:
    442             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))

/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    126     def deco(*a, **kw):
    127         try:
--> 128             return f(*a, **kw)
    129         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    130             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o244.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 4, jupyter-h11910677, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 605, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 597, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 271, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 107, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 612, in prepare
    verify_func(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1408, in verify
    verify_value(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1395, in verify_struct
    raise TypeError(new_msg("StructType can not accept object %r in type %s"
TypeError: StructType can not accept object 'Free PDF version\r  \n\r  \n[https://canvas.umn.edu/courses/188156/files/16432145](https://canvas.umn.edu/courses/188156/files/16432145) \r  \n\r  \nPhysical copy for purchase\r  \n\r  \n[https://www.akpress.org/undoing-border-imperialism.html](https://www.akpress.org/undoing-border-imperialism.html) \r  \n\r  \nText to speech reader for audio form\r  \n\r  \n[https://www.naturalreaders.com/online/](https://www.naturalreaders.com/online/) \n\nSubreddit for further discussion r/AnarchoBooks' in type <class 'str'>

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:503)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:638)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:621)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:489)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:729)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:872)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:872)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2008)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2239)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2188)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2177)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2120)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:467)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:420)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3627)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2697)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3618)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3616)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2697)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2904)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:337)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 605, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 597, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 271, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 107, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 612, in prepare
    verify_func(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1408, in verify
    verify_value(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1395, in verify_struct
    raise TypeError(new_msg("StructType can not accept object %r in type %s"
TypeError: StructType can not accept object 'Free PDF version\r  \n\r  \n[https://canvas.umn.edu/courses/188156/files/16432145](https://canvas.umn.edu/courses/188156/files/16432145) \r  \n\r  \nPhysical copy for purchase\r  \n\r  \n[https://www.akpress.org/undoing-border-imperialism.html](https://www.akpress.org/undoing-border-imperialism.html) \r  \n\r  \nText to speech reader for audio form\r  \n\r  \n[https://www.naturalreaders.com/online/](https://www.naturalreaders.com/online/) \n\nSubreddit for further discussion r/AnarchoBooks' in type <class 'str'>

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:503)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:638)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:621)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:489)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:729)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:872)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:872)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an RDD of type `RDD[Tuple[str]]` but in your code, the line:

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(comments)
```

returns `RDD[str]` which then fails when you try to convert it to dataframe with that given schema.

Try modifying that line to:

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(c,) for c in comments])
```

---

Note that you can actually pass list of tuples directly to `spark.createDataFrame` like this:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(c,) for c in comments], schema=schema)

df.show()
#+--------+
#|Comments|
#+--------+
#| string1|
#| string2|
#| string3|
#+--------+
```